# Error with lagged predictors variable lengths differ

Tags: r, function, lag

I am trying to fit a model with lag 1 as predictor, please note my predictor contains two column :  the return of asset 1  and the return of assets 2,

first I fitted as follow :

```
lag1<-lag(data.train,k=1) 


llqr(lag1, y, tau = 0.5, m = 50)
```

> Error in llqr(lag1, y, tau = 0.5, m = 50) : Data include missing
> values.

the missing data is because of the lag.

then I tried to use na.omit for the lag missing data

```
lag1<-na.omit(lag(data.train,k=1))
llqr(lag1, y, tau = 0.5, m = 50)
```

and I received this error :

> Error in llqr(lag1, y, tau = 0.5, m = 50) : Error in
> model.frame.default(formula = y ~ z, weights = w, drop.unused.levels =
> TRUE) :    variable lengths differ

R function llqr required y must be the same length as x.

any recommendations the fix the error please ?

Comment: try `llqr(lag1, y[-1], tau = 0.5, m = 50)`

Comment: I tried it , it says : Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ z, weights = w, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')